# ExecutorService service not executing all threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);    

outerArray.forEach(entry -> executorService.submit(() ->
          innerArray.add(updateEntry(params...)))));
executorService.shutdown();
```

Looking at the above code, the length of innerArray after the shutdown of executorService is supposed to be the same with outerArray.
But the length of innerArray is always 1 - 5.
From my observation, some executions are skipped.

The length of outerArray is usually around 2 thousand.

I've tried changing the length of the thread pool but it isn't working.

Comment: Is innerArray thread-safe?

Comment: Add some debugging, e.g. printing of array size before and after each insert within the runnable, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. innerArray is just a List which is used to store the objects returned by updateEntry. @MatteoNNZ

Comment: @Dikum if you have 3 threads concurrently adding objects to an array that is not synchronized, there's no guarantee the add will actually work. I think you should use [synchronizedLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) instead of simple lists.

Comment: @luk2302 I tried that. It printed figures like 0, 0, 0, 3. It repeated the length in multiple places.

Comment: I tried something similar (with a very simple calculation). With a regular `ArrayList`, an input of 2000 items leads to a result of 1951 items. If I turn `innerArray` into a concurrent list (in this case, a simple `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`, I get the 2000 items I expected. So I think Matteo NNZ is spot-on.

Comment: Thanks guys! Using synchronozedList solved the problem. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Dikum Now draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Comment: Agree with @BasilBourque you should post it as answer to help people with the same problem in the future. About the reason, an array list is implemented with an array behind. When you add/remove, the array is resized and your element is added at the end. If multiple threads do this on the same object in a non-synchronized way, they may happen to get the same index and write two elements one after the other on the same place, so you only see the last one. In general, when more than one thread does write operation on an object, the access to the object should be serial to avoid race conditions

Comment: Making the List a synchronized List solved it. Reason being what @MatteoNNZ has pointed out.

`ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);  

List<SomeObject> innerArray= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

outerArray.forEach(entry -> executorService.submit(() ->
          innerArray.add(updateEntry(params...)))));
executorService.shutdown();`