# How to correctly use the Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following task :

Create Class called: ElementsProvider(int n, List elements) that will provide N random elements into given list.
Elements Provider will be an thread.
Try create 4 instances, each of this instance will add 1000 random elements into the list.
start all instances at once and wait until they end.
print list size.

And here is what is did ,

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ElementsProvider implements Runnable{
    private final List<Integer> list;
    private final int n;

    public ElementsProvider(List<Integer> list, int n){
        this.list = list;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(random.nextInt());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = 1000;
        ElementsProvider e1 = new ElementsProvider(list, n);
        ElementsProvider e2 = new ElementsProvider(list, n);
        ElementsProvider e3 = new ElementsProvider(list, n);
        ElementsProvider e4 = new ElementsProvider(list, n);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(e1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(e2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(e3);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(e4);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Apparently I got that the task is not ok.

Feedback that I got is :

wrong, try to print list size, it will be different each time You run the program.

Can  someone point me where  I am  mistaking  please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491550/executorservice-service-not-executing-all-threads, especially the comments.

Comment: The person who set you the assignment has already given you feedback which they think will help you get to the right answer. We can't help you without undermining the learning goals of the exercise. If you think their feedback is not direct enough, speak to them and tell them that.

Comment: you can also use wait() with a duration constructors, instead of join()

Comment: @TusharDeshpande  if I use wait()    my task will run the same , 
I have the situation that   my size list is always changing instead of staying toe same number as expected

Comment: What do you think the requirement and feedback mean by "print list size"?

Comment: @vsfDawg ,  Output should be  4000  as I add 1000 random elements in each  , if I `sout(list.size())`  I don't  get  4000 always as supposed  , so  by using   `join()` it looks that my threads  dose not add all elements and is skipping

Comment: @Michael , So if I understand good I  jsut should  put   start thread and then join  and stard and join ? EXAMPle:  ` t1.start(); t1.join();t2.start(); t2.join();t3.start();t3.join() t4.start(); t4.join();`

Comment: Well that's quite a bad way to solve it.

Comment: indeed @Kayaman , that also  is not ok since my Threads will not run simultaneously , can you please  help  me on this ?

Comment: I suppose you've learned about some kind of synchronization before you were given this homework? Or the problems of parallel programming were discussed, and how you can't just do things carelessly with multiple threads (like your program is doing). A regular `ArrayList` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Kayaman , indeed I learned  about synchronization

Comment: You say you learned about synchronization, but if that's true, then why are you mystified by the fact that your program (which uses _no_ synchronization) does not "get 4000 always as supposed?" You say, "my Threads will not run simultaneously." Do you understand what threads _are?_ The complete and only purpose for having threads is to run things _concurrently_ (not exactly the same as "simultaneously," but close enough for this conversation.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow , I assume that is because I am totally new in to Threads and I may not have fully got the  point :(, that is why I asked for help so I can better get the point , like you just said now:)

Comment: Well, look at what you learned. Maybe you can synchronize access to the list (you'll need an object shared by all the threads for that).

Comment: @Kayaman, I look into it and I did it this way , output after  5 time running is always 4000 , can you please let le know if that is the correct way ?
    `@Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (ElementsProvider.class) {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                list.add(random.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Ideally, you should ask your instructor or a TA for your class if you don't understand the feedback that you got from them. But TLDR: `t1.start()` returns _immediately,_ and then the `t1` thread can run concurrently with the main thread. You `start()` four threads that all can concurrently access the same list. But they do it with no synchronization, and that's a Bad Thing. You should use a `synchronized` statement to ensure that no two threads can ever be in a `list.add()` call at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the point @SolomonSlow , I have posted above the new way  that is I used synchronization for the Run method , I get the correct  output , hope that is a correct/good  way

Comment: Your code prevents two `run()` methods from running at the same time. Ideally synchronized blocks are as small as possible.

Comment: @Kayaman , so to understand by that that where I used synchronized I did good ? 
I assume I did good because my output is now 4000 each time I run the program and indeed  all tasks run at the same time + wait for all to be done then I have the list size()

Comment: The program is more correct regarding threads than it was before, yes. We should still avoid hanging on to locks for longer than necessary, and using `ElementsProvider.class` is a dubious choice to lock on. A better choice would be for example `list`, and you really only need to synchronize the thread-unsafe operation you're doing, which is adding elements from multiple threads to a non-threadsafe `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proposed this change in a comment on your original question, above:

> ```java
> @Override
> public void run() {
>     synchronized (ElementsProvider.class) {
>         Random random = new Random();
>         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>             list.add(random.nextInt());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

O.K., That will ensure that your program always prints the correct answer, but it does so by making your program *effectively* single-threaded. When you put the entire body of the threads' `run()` method in a single `synchronized` block, you prevent them from running concurrently. But, running concurrently is the *only* reason to use threads.

You need to synchronize a smaller part of the code. The only variable that the threads share is the `list`. There is no reason for `new Random()` to be inside the `synchronized` block, and there is no reason for `random.nextInt()` to be inside it. The only thing that needs to be inside the `synchronized` block is the `list.add()` call.

Comment: So in my case  I can do this  up to what i understand  from you ,
`synchronized (list) {.....}`  ?

Comment: Like this I sync only the list right?

Comment: @BecaNr1, `synchronized(list)` does _not_ "sync only the list." This is one of the more confusing corners of Java. `synchronized(o)` doesn't "lock" `o`. All it does is, it prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same `o` at the same time. What is "locked" in a synchronized statement is whatever you put inside the block. I'm saying, put the `list.add()` call inside the block. And yeah, you can choose to use `list` as the lock object, or you can choose to use `ElementsProvider.class` as the lock object. Just make sure that all of the threads use the _same_ lock object.

Comment: Thanks for information's.
I have   the list.add() inside the synchronized methods

`synchronized (list) {//synchronized
         list.add(random.nextInt()); }`

Comment: I assume that this it will be a better solution.         'List<Integer> numbers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());'

Comment: @BecaNr1, For your specific problem, in which there is only _one_ shared variable, yes. Using `synchronizedList(...)` is a convenient way to solve it. But in a more general case, where you need locking to protect a relationship between two or more shared variables, then you still will need to know how to do it the `synchronized` way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a static semaphore to the your `ElementsProvider` class:

```
public class ElementsProvider implements Runnable {
    private final List<Integer> list;
    private final int n;
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    public ElementsProvider(List<Integer> list, int n) {
        this.list = list;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(n); 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            l.add(random.nextInt());
        }

        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("Adding " + l.size() + " elements to list");
            list.addAll(l);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this would work, I suspect the students in this course have not been introduced to the java.util.concurrent package yet.

Comment: That indeed works also , Thanks for support , I will give a go to the synchronized method :)

Comment: Why `static`? The data that the semaphore protects (i.e., `List<Integer> list`) is not `static`. Normal practice is to declare the lock object near the declaration(s) of the data that it protects, and for it to have the same scope and extent as the data that it protects.

Comment: Because then all of the instances of the class are sharing the same semaphore.  it saves from having to create the semaphore and passing it to each instance of the class manually.

Comment: D'Oh! I overlooked the fact that the `list` is provided through the constructor. But note! If the list is passed in from other code, then there's no guarantee that the other code won't operate on the list independently of the `ElementsProvider` class. Only problem there is, your `private static Semaphore` is unavailable to code outside of `ElementsProvider`. I'm sticking with what I said above: Declare a lock object near the declaration of the data it protects. If the protected object is passed in through a constructor call, then the lock had better also be passed in as the next parameter.